# Making Images all the same size

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a simple website but I downloaded some images but I wanted them to have the same size/layout.

[image]

```
<div>

@*Linha 1*@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="portrait" id="bf1" src="~/Content/Images/battlefield1.png" alt="" onmouseover="ChangeImageMouseOver();" onmouseout="ChangeImageMouseOut();">
        </a>
        <h3>
            Gaming
        </h3>
        <p>Upon yielding, kind sea subdue very seed sixth them lesser one lesser there earth days were multiply so sixth gathering fifth that man fowl made.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="portrait" src="~/Content/Images/assetto corsa.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <h3>
            Gaming
        </h3>
        <p>Upon yielding, kind sea subdue very seed sixth them lesser one lesser there earth days were multiply so sixth gathering fifth that man fowl made.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <a href="@Url.Action("CSGO","PC")">
            <img class="portrait" src="~/Content/Images/csgo.jpeg" alt="" >
        </a>
        <h3>
            Gaming
        </h3>
        <p>Upon yielding, kind sea subdue very seed sixth them lesser one lesser there earth days were multiply so sixth gathering fifth that man fowl made.</p>
    </div>
</div>

@*Linha 2*@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="portrait" src="~/Content/Images/dota2.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <h3>
            Gaming
        </h3>
        <p>Upon yielding, kind sea subdue very seed sixth them lesser one lesser there earth days were multiply so sixth gathering fifth that man fowl made.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="portrait" src="~/Content/Images/fifa17.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
        <h3>
            Gaming
        </h3>
        <p>Upon yielding, kind sea subdue very seed sixth them lesser one lesser there earth days were multiply so sixth gathering fifth that man fowl made.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
        <a href="#">
            <img class="portrait" src="~/Content/Images/LoL.png" alt="">
        </a>
        <h3>
            Gaming
        </h3>
        <p>Upon yielding, kind sea subdue very seed sixth them lesser one lesser there earth days were multiply so sixth gathering fifth that man fowl made.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a css file and use styles.  Then apply the style to the images.

Comment: What is with all the kisses at the end of the post? Anyway why not just set the width and height in the image tag? You can go this via CSS or HTML. Choose the former

Comment: Please help with code. I just begun playing with this.

Comment: I would suggest you take the css tutorial at w3schools.com.  https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: Use a css style for width and height learn more here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp

Comment: Why are all of the XXXXXXXXX necessary at the end of your post?

Comment: @Lexi - The poster loves you?!

Comment: If the images have different aspect ratios, you won't be able to get uniform width & height without either A) cropping them B) setting them to a background image on a fixed width/height element with overflow hidden (some portion will be cut off) C) distorting the aspect ratios. If your site is static content (only 6 images for example, I would go with A). If your images are dynamically served from an API, go with B

Comment: @xDDD adding that extra text at the end just to get it to post is unnecessary. You should write a more detailed and specific question to naturally get past the error you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have substituted my own images for display purposes, but it's the css here that matters (you can link it in as a separate css stylesheet - recommended - or put the style in `<style>` tags in the head of the html document)

In my css I have set a max-height for the images, but if your images are of varying heights, it's probably better that you set the height to auto. (my images are about 120 anyway, some slightly over ~125)

```css
#wrapper {
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.row div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}

a img {
  width: 95%;
  max-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
      <a href="#">
        <!--  <img class="portrait" id="bf1" src="~/Content/Images/battlefield1.png" alt="battlefield" onmouseover="ChangeImageMouseOver();" onmouseout="ChangeImageMouseOut();">-->
        <img class="portrait" id="bf1" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/autumntrees.jpg" alt="Trees" />
      </a>
      <h3>
        Gaming
      </h3>
      <p>Upon yielding, kind sea subdue very seed sixth them lesser one lesser there earth days were multiply so sixth gathering fifth that man fowl made.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
      <!--  <a href="#">
            <img class="portrait" src="~/Content/Images/assetto corsa.jpg" alt="CORSA">    </a>-->
      <a> <img class="portrait" id="bf1" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/babytiger.jpg" alt="tiger" /></a>
      <h3>
        Gaming
      </h3>
      <p>Upon yielding, kind sea subdue very seed sixth them lesser one lesser there earth days were multiply so sixth gathering fifth that man fowl made.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
      <!--    <a href="@Url.Action('CSGO','PC')">
            <img class="portrait" src="~/Content/Images/csgo.jpeg" alt="CSGO" >
        </a>--->
      <a> <img class="portrait" id="bf1" src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/daffodils1.jpg" alt="Daffodils" /></a>
      <h3>
        Gaming
      </h3>
      <p>Upon yielding, kind sea subdue very seed sixth them lesser one lesser there earth days were multiply so sixth gathering fifth that man fowl made.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I put an id on your containing div - ids help to differentiate especially when you have a hierarchy of divs

Best of luck

Comment: for best results view the snippet full screen. There is a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/zh2wzwa0/